# Is it rude to thank someone with “Vous êtes très utile”?

Tags: politesse

Is it polite to thank someone by saying that they are “utile”?

I want to say the equivalent of “You were very *helpful*, thank you”. But I'm wondering whether “Vous êtiez très utile” is too blunt, coming off like “You were very *useful*”, as if they were a tool.

I'm not sure about the nuance of “Votre aide m'est utile” too. Is it a polite way of thanking someone for their *helpfulness*, or just a way of telling them that I find them *useful* to me?

Comment: Calling smeone other than yourself *utile* makes it sound like they are a tool, a slave or a henchman to you.

Comment: Most of all, it sounds very *unFrench*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on the context, but in general it is better to avoid that.

You can say, for your particular case:

- *Merci pour votre aide précieuse*: Thank you for your precious help
- *Votre aide m'a été utile*: You have been helpful

But *utile* can be used positively in French language:

- *Bonjour, puis-je vous être utile?*: Hello, can I help you?/do you need help?